# Sequence vs Progression

Tags: sequences-and-series, terminology

I understand the difference between these two terms. My textbook says that terms in a *sequence* follow some definite rule, or an algorithm, and it’s not always possible to express its general term via a mathematical expression.

Example : A sequence of consecutive prime numbers.

While each terms of a *progression* follows the same rule and we have a mathematical expression for any arbitrary term of a progression.

My problem is, I don’t fully understand this sentence **terms of a progression follow the same rule.**

Can they follow more than **one** rule? Let’s say we have a general term for a sequence

$T_n = \begin{cases}
  \frac{1}{n}  & \text{if } n \in \{1,2,3,...10\}, \\ 
  \frac{-1}{n} & \text{if } n \in \{11,12,.....,20\} \\
  \frac{-1}{3n}& \text{if } n \in \{21,22, \ldots\}
\end{cases}
$

Now we can find any arbitrary term of this sequence because we have its general term (with more than a single mathematical expression). Is it a *sequence* or a *progression*?

My own understanding of sequence vs progression says that it should be a progression. If it is, can a progression have a general term which has more than one mathematical expression?

Comment: I don't think anyone but textbook writers worries about these distinctions. For what it's worth, when I use the term *sequence*, I don't imagine it to be following any definite rule or algorithm; it's just an arbitrary assignment of a mathematical object to each natrual number.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A [sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence) is a function whose domain is an interval of integers. The domain is often the set of natural numbers. Sequences are usually denoted using a subscript rather than in parentheses, that is, $T_n$ rather than $T(n)$.

In mathematics, the term *progression* is mostly used with a qualifying adjective:
[arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression) progression, [geometric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression) progression, [harmonic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_progression_(mathematics)) progression.

An *arithmetic progression* is a sequence of numbers such that the difference between any two consecutive terms is constant. 
A *geometric progression* is a sequence of numbers such that the quotient of any two consecutive terms is constant.
A *harmonic progression* is a sequence formed by taking the inverses of an arithmetic progression.

Coming back to your examples, the sequences $\frac{1}{n}$ and $\frac{-1}{n} = \frac{1}{-n}$ and $\frac{-1}{3n} = \frac{1}{-3n}$ are harmonic progressions since $n$, $-n$ and $-3n$ are arithmetic progressions. Now you can only say that the sequence $T_n$ is the disjoint union of three harmonic progressions.

Comment: Thanks for explaining it. The general term $T_n$ in my original post contains all three expressions. It is a single general term, that contains three expressions for different values of $n$. Sorry, it is my mistake. I did not use the right notation. I have not fully learnt mathjax yet, I am still learning. Now I understand that writing $T_n$ three times would make it look like three different sequences. I have edited my post

Comment: If you wish, you could use $R_n$, $S_n$ and $T_n$ to clearly indicate you consider three different sequences.

Comment: I understand what I did wrong. Sorry again for that. Actually that is a single sequence, not three different sequences. I am not sure whether we'd call it just a sequence, or a progression as well (based on the definition of a progression)

Comment: I understand now. I just edited your question, please let me know if you agree. Then I will also update my answer...

Comment: The question is correct now. Thanks a lot for editing it. I did not know how to add that big bracket

Comment: I already did it actually by adding the last sentence.

Comment: Sorry I did not see that last sentence. $T_n$ is a disjoint union of three HPs. So that makes $T_n$ a *progression*, right? Because it is just a union of three different progressions?

Comment: As I said, you rarely use *progression* without one of the qualifying adjectives I have listed in my answer. Since none of them apply to $T_n$, I would call it a *sequence* and just add as a comment it is a disjoint union of three HPs.

Comment: Got it, thanks! My textbook has explained the two terms *sequence* and *progression* separately, followed by types of progression. So it got me wondering whether a general term like this one would be called (just) a sequence or a progression. Clear as water now. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Marriam-Webster Dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/progression)

> progression: a sequence of numbers in which each term is related to its predecessor by uniform law.

In this definition, Fibonacci sequences, for instance, cannot be considered progressions since each term of these sequences is dependent not only on one but on two predecessors: 
$u_{n+2}=u_{n+1}+u_{n}$

Even Quadratic sequence $1^{2}, 2^{2},3^{3} ...$ cannot be called a progression by this definition because the quadratic sequence formula, which includes only one predecessor, is not defined by any uniform law, but rather is dependent on n:
$u_{n+1}=(n+1)^{2}=n^{2}+2n+1=u_{n}+2n+1$

Therefore, the sequence $T_{n}$ in this question is no longer a progression, even though it consists of three progressions, because its terms no longer depend only on the previous term but also on n.