# What is the difference between Sequence and Progression

Tags: sequences-and-series, prime-numbers, terminology

I know this question has already been asked once on [this page](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3530240/sequence-vs-progression#:%7E:text=1%20Answer&text=A%20sequence%20is%20a%20function%20whose%20domain%20is%20an%20interval%20of%20integers.&text=An%20arithmetic%20progression%20is%20a,two%20consecutive%20terms%20is%20constant.). But I find the answer given not making a  distinction between the two clearly.

The author says that "A sequence is a function whose domain is an interval of integers. The domain is often the set of natural numbers." I agree. He describes Progressive as "mostly used with a qualifying adjective"
I didn't quite understand the difference apart from the fact that

1-If there exists a common difference between consecutive numbers they are specifically called an arithmetic progression

2-If there exists a common ratio between consecutive numbers they are specifically called geometric progression

And similarly for Harmonic Progression too

---

Now what I think the difference is, Sequence is a function of natural numbers meaning for the first natural number, you have one specific output and so on. One example could be Prime numbers (an example which I think I picked up some other site).

So for the First Prime number you have 2, Second Prime number you have 3 and so on.

Progression, on the other hand, is also a function of natural numbers, but this time there's a mathematical correlation between the natural numbers and their images (or the output). This is why AP, GP, HP are all Progressions. The same should be applying for all other similar functions too right?

Now coming back to the difference between Sequence and Progression. In the case of the Sequence of Prime numbers, there does not exist any mathematical correlation that enables us to tell us the 1001th Prime number. Is this the difference?

(This is what I think the answer is. Moreover, I still haven't gotten my comment privilege to ask my doubt and if I had answered it was likely that no one would have replied seeing that a correct answer has already been chosen and the system tends to favour unanswered question more. Coming to my second doubt in the same page, doesn't the OPs example count as progressive or is it a sequence like the Correct answer tell)

Comment: It's simply that certain kinds of sequences have traditionally been called "progressions."  Other than the three you mention, I can't think of any.  This isn't important at all,  mathematically speaking.

Comment: @saulspatz: I have very occasionally seen sequences of the form $x_n=a^n(b+nd)$ for fixed $a,b,d$ called *arithmetico-geometric progressions*, but that’s the only other use of the term that I can recall.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Me too; I forgot about those.