# Can a progression have a general term which has more than one mathematical expression?

Tags: sequences-and-series

[Sequence vs Progression](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3530240/sequence-vs-progression)

It is based on this topic here. Apparently, the question on whether the example of the poster can be considered a sequence was not answered. The example is a sequence with its formula expressed as a piecewise function. Although a comment has said the following. "I don't think anyone but textbook writers worries about these distinctions. For what it's worth, when I use the term sequence, I don't imagine it to be following any definite rule or algorithm; it's just an arbitrary assignment of a mathematical object to each natural number."

The thing is, what if I am interested on knowing the answer to the question for the sake of answering even though these distinctions just matter in textbooks? Let us stick to the idea that a progression is a sequence which can be expressed in terms of a formula. Does any reference say that a sequence expressed as a piecewise function can be counted as a progression? I mean, there has to be some textbooks that have answered this and not resort to the "It doesn't matter that much".

Comment: Arithmetic/geometric/harmonic/etc progressions are particular types of sequences. They also happen to all have closed forms ("*formulas*"). Other than that, I have not seen the term "progression" used generically. If *you* have, please cite the sources and quote the full context.

Comment: Just gonna give an example of a link and not quote.
https://www.quora.com/How-does-sequence-and-progression-differ
But yes, I have also not seen sources if you restrict it to textbooks.